# How to display asterisk rectangle with content?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Using the code found on [C# Corner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/print-rectangle-of-stars-in-c-sharp), I am trying to create an asterisk rectangle with a text content but it doesn't seem to work. It prints the text "Program to Print Rectangle *'s", but not the rectangle. Any ideas on how I can achieve this? The code looks like below:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int height = 5;
        int width = 5;

        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++)
            {
                if ((i == 1 || i == height) || (j == 1 || j == width))
                {
                    Console.Write("*"); //prints at border place
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" "); //prints inside other than border
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pro Tip, its nice to look at well formatted code.

Comment: You must have copied your code wrong or modified it, or not entering values or something. as this is working as expected https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/y0cg5E

Comment: yes your question is a little confusing, you need to state how where when you want to add content to that rectangle

Comment: @MichaelRandall, I want the text to appear inside the box.

Comment: What if you content is too long? do you want it centred, wrapped, ect ect ect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
string myText = "Hello World";
int width = myText.Length + 2, height = 3;
for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++)
    {
        if ((i == 1 || i == height) || (j == 1 || j == width))
            Console.Write("*"); //prints at border place
        else
            Console.Write(myText[j - 2]); //prints inside other than border
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```